# Is there a way to debug transactions in RSK network, which could be the best way?

Tags: debugging, smartcontracts, geth, rsk

We are running an RSK node, some smart contract transactions show internal errors, but the message related to the failed `require` condition doesn't appear in those error messages...

We only see "internal error" and are unable to see which specific error occurred.

Answer (score 6):

If your contract emits messages in the reversions, then you can find them out by using `debug_traceTransaction`.

**NOTE:** The `debug` RPC module is enabled by default in RSK config, but this is disabled on public nodes.

Furthermore, the RSK public nodes do not expose this feature, and you must run your own node in order to do so.

The following assumes that you have a local node running with RPC exposed on port `4444`.

First, you need to enable `debug` module in your config file:

```json
modules = [
    ...
    {
        "name": "debug",
        "version": "1.0",
        "enabled": "true",
    },
    ...
]
```

Then, you can execute the RPC method passing the
transaction ID as a parameter, like in this example:

```sh
curl \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
    --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"debug_traceTransaction","params":["0xa9ae08f01437e32973649cc13f6db44e3ef370cbcd38a6ed69806bd6ea385e49"],"id":1}' \
    http://localhost:4444
```

You will get the following response
(truncated for brevity):

```json
{
    ... 
    "result": "08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e536166654d6174683a207375627472616374696f6e206f766572666c6f770000",
    "error": "",
    "reverted": true,
    ...
}
```

Finally, convert `result` from hexadecimal to ASCII,
to obtain a readable message:

```
Ãy  SafeMath: subtraction overflow
```